# Emacs : Redefining command in Haskell-mode (haskell-mode-hook)

Tags: haskell, emacs, macros, elisp, haskell-mode

in emacs in haskell-mode, I wanted to change the command

- "C-x C-s"

to

- "C-x C-s" followed by "C-c C-l".

Taking a cue from : [Haskell.org : Emacs/Keybindings and simple usage](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Keybindings_and_simple_usage) I tried inserting the following variants into the .emacs file but they did not work. Any suggestions as to how I might go about implementing the functionality above would be most welcomed! Thanks.

***Variant 1***

```
(defun haskell-hook ()
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-s") (kbd "C-x C-s C-c C-l"))

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-hook)
```

***Variant 2***

```
(defun haskell-hook ()
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-s") 'my-haskell-mode-save-buffer)

(defun my-haskell-mode-save-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-kbd-macro [?\C-s ?\C-x ?\C-c ?\C-l return]))

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-hook)
```

---

---

***[EDIT 1]*** @Tikhon Jelvis : that was definitely a good learning exercise! Thanks. Using the methods outlined in your post I changed your function to :

```
(defun my-haskell-mode-save-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (inferior-haskell-load-file)
  (other-window 1))
```

where the last line programmatically switches the cursor to the interactive window. Thank you.

***[EDIT2]*** Other variants include :

```
(defun my-haskell-mode-save-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-kbd-macro (read-kbd-macro "C-c C-l"))
  (other-window 1))
```

and :

```
(defun my-haskell-mode-save-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-kbd-macro [?\C-c ?\C-l])
  (other-window 1))
```

Comment: You can bind a keyboard sequence to a command, not another keyboard sequence. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I want "C-s C-x" to first save the file and then automatically load the file in the launcher, rather than just saving the file. Thanks

Comment: Look for a `haskell-mode-after-save-hook` or create a function which does this. `(defun my-haskell-save-buffer (buf) (interactive ...) (save-buffer buf) (haskell-launch buf) )` ... Proof of concept, look up how to pass the current buffer with `interactive` and the exact command for "the launcher".

Comment: It might make more sense to bind saving the file then loading to `C-c C-l` rather than loading the file every time you save it.

Comment: @vivian : It was just an experiment for me to learn about emacs. As Tikhon Jelvis points out "C-c C-l" already saves so (apart from the moving of the cursor between buffers) there is not really any value added by the functionality above! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is run the function that `C-x C-s` runs followed by running the function `C-c C-l` does. You can find out what function is run by some key binding via `C-h k`. That is, first type `C-h k` then the key command you're interested in.

This gives us `(save-buffer &optional ARGS)` for `C-x C-s` and `(inferior-haskell-load-file &optional RELOAD)` for `C-c C-l`. The `&optional` means exactly what you think it does--that argument is optional, so we don't care about it.

Now write the function that does both of them:

```
(defun my-haskell-mode-save-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (inferior-haskell-load-file))
```

Now you can bind this function to `C-x C-s` in haskell mode exactly how you've been doing it:

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () 
                                (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'my-haskell-mode-save-buffer)))
```

EDIT: It seems `C-c C-l` saves your file by default before loading it. This means you can just write

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'inferior-haskell-load-file)))
```

and have exactly the same effect without writing your own function. However, I think writing it my way is a good learning exercise :P. That approach works whenever you want to combine multiple different key bindings into one.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work in the year 2020. To fix it, you'd have to replace `(inferior-haskell-load-file)` with `(haskell-process-load-file)`.

So the function after fixing is

```
(defun haskell-mode-save-load-buffer ()
      (interactive)
      (save-buffer)
      (haskell-process-load-file))
```